# 3-step process to make propyl ethanoate from propene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

I was asked to make propyl ethanoate from propene in three steps. I have access to the reactions below.

- Nucleophilic substitution (Both SN1 and SN2)
- Electrophilic addition
- Hydrogenation
- Dehydration
- Hydration
- Condensation
- Free radical substitution
- Oxidation of alcohols

I'm assuming that you can add whatever reactants you want, since propyl ethanoate has five carbons and you can't just chop a carbon off of a propene with the above reactions. I know that the final step has to be condensation, since that's how you make esters. So essentially, I need a two-step process to make a primary alcohol that becomes the propyl in propyl ethanoate.

If you use hydrogenation on propene first, you get propane. Once you have that, it takes two steps to make a primary alcohol: one in free radical substitution (to get 1-bromopropane) and one in nucleophilic substitution (to get propan-1-ol).

If you use hydration first, you get a secondary alcohol in one step. However, you can't make propyl ethanoate with propan-2-ol.

If you use electrophilic addition first, you get a secondary haloalkane (2-bromopropane). That can also only get you a secondary alcohol.

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm convinced that it's impossible to do.

Comment: Indeed, with the reactions you have, I'm not sure how you get to the ester in 3 steps. Of course it becomes extremely simple if you use something outside of your syllabus, but well...

Comment: Can you suggest something like that? That would be helpful as well.

Comment: is it ethyl ethanoate or propyl ethanoate?the heading says ethyl ethanoate and the description has matter dealing with propyl ethanoate...

Comment: Sorry about that! It's propyl ethanoate.

Answer (score 9):

My proposal is [hydroboration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroboration) followed by Fischer esterification. It's 2 or 3 steps depending on how many you count hydroboration to be.

[image: Reaction]

Alternatively if you are intent on going through a haloalkane pathway, you could try [anti-Markovnikov addition of $\ce{HBr}$](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Core/Organic_Chemistry/Hydrocarbons/Alkenes/Reactivity_of_Alkenes/Radical_Additions--Anti-Markovnikov_Product_Formation) by reacting it in the presence of $\ce{H2O2}$ to prepare 1-bromopropane. Then you could do nucleophilic substitution of $\ce{OH-}$ followed by Fischer esterification. This method would have a lower yield though due to the competing E2 reaction.

Comment: Could you explain how one would consider the above procedure to contain either two or three steps? By the way, how do you draw such nice chemical equations?

Comment: @DefinitelyNotAPlesiosaur with ChemDraw. And it's two steps if you consider the entirety of hydroboration as one step, or three if you consider borane addition and $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{H2O2}$ addition as separate steps. If you don't want to use my proposed one, the alternative one is definitely three steps.

Comment: Essentially, I need to get  a primary alcohol from an alkene. Do you think that I could do this with electrophilic addition in some special solution (like a protic solution) or in some special conditions (like extreme temperature)?

Comment: Yes...that is exactly what the [alternative method](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Core/Organic_Chemistry/Hydrocarbons/Alkenes/Reactivity_of_Alkenes/Radical_Additions--Anti-Markovnikov_Product_Formation) is. Special conditions by which an acid ($\ce{HBr}$) adds to the alkene to form a primary haloalkane, which can then be used to form the primary alcohol.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way.

1. Oxidise propene to prop-2-en-1-ol with selenium dioxide. Here's a reference: [*J. Org. Chem.*, **1979**, *44*, 4683](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00393a045)

   [image: SeO2 allylic oxidation mechanism]
2. Esterify. The typical Fischer esterification (with carboxylic acid and concentrated sulfuric acid) should probably work, although there are many other possibilities. One is to use the acyl chloride with a weak base. The weak base serves as a [nucleophilic catalyst](http://chemistrytextbookcrawl.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/nucleophilic-catalysts.html), and also helps to mop up the $\ce{HCl}$ produced in the reaction. A common choice is 4-dimethylaminopyridine, often called DMAP. Another option is to use the carboxylic acid with dicyclohexylcarbodiimide (DCC) and DMAP. The DCC activates the carboxylic acid in what is known as the [Steglich esterification](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/steglich-esterification.shtm).

   [image: Esterification]
3. Reduce the double bond by catalytic hydrogenation. C=C double bonds are generally more susceptible to catalytic hydrogenation than C=O double bonds (disclaimer: this may vary depending on the catalyst and conditions chosen), so this reaction can proceed chemoselectively to give the desired product, *n*-propyl acetate:

   [image: Hydrogenation]